# How do I make a date to date calculator with assigned value per month for daily charge

Tags: php

I want to make a php calculator.
First i want it to have an assigned value per day for every month. For example marchs daily value is $12 and January is $7.
Based on these values I want the calculator to calculate daily charges from selected date calendar.
And then the total cost.
Any ideas how I can do it? Any articles that can help me?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand (dates have dollar values?)  Does every month or day of the year have a unique value?  Are they according to a formula, or arbitrary?  Are they constants?  How will the user interact with your program?  Can you give some more complete examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you on your way. First set start and end date for the period. The logic then stores the 'days' for each month in `$dates[]` and sums the days for each month, stored in `$daysPerMonth[]`. Finally, using the `$charges[]` array, rotate through the days in each month and multiply by the set charges.

Array `totalCharges[]` shows the totals per month. Grand total, the overall total for the period.

```
<?php
$start = "2021-01-01";
$end = "2022-01-10";
$start = new DateTime($start);
$end = new DateTime($end);

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); // include end date
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

// store dates
$dates = [];
$format = 'm'; // only month is of interest
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dates[] = $date->format($format);
}

$daysPerMonth = array_count_values($dates); // count days per month
// set charges per month
$charges = ['01' => 7, '02' => 9, '03' => 12, '04' => 13, '05' => 14, '06' => 15,
    '07' => 16, '08' => 15, '09' => 12, '10' => 9, '11' => 8, '12' => 7];
$totalCharges = []; // store total charges per month
foreach($charges as $monthly => $charge) {
    foreach($daysPerMonth as $month => $days) {
        if($monthly == $month) $totalCharges[$month] = $charge * $days;
    }
}


print_r($totalCharges); // total charges per month


echo 'Grand Total : ' . array_sum($totalCharges);
```